# Decomposition of a matrix into observability and controllability matrices

Tags: matrix-decomposition, signal-processing, symmetric-matrices, svd, hankel-matrices

$\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{
  \kern1mu\raise1pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise4pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}
  \kern1mu
}}$

I have a matrix $\boldsymbol{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ in Hankel form and I would like to decompose it into Observability matrix $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ times the controllability matrix $\boldsymbol{\Delta} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$. Here, $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$ is anti-upper triangular matrix and $\boldsymbol{\Delta}$ is a lower triangular matrix.

$\boldsymbol{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{b} & \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{Ab} & \dots & \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{A}^{M-1}\boldsymbol{b} \\
        \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{Ab} &  & \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{A}^{M-1}\boldsymbol{b} & 0\\
        \vdots & \iddots & \iddots & \vdots\\
        \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{A}^{M-1}\boldsymbol{b} & 0 & \dots & 0 
    \end{bmatrix} $

$ \boldsymbol{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{c}^T \\ \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{A} \\ \vdots \\ \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{A}^{M-1} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{b} & \boldsymbol{Ab} & \dots & \boldsymbol{A}^{M-1}\boldsymbol{b} \end{bmatrix} = 
 \boldsymbol{\Gamma}\boldsymbol{\Delta}.
    $

To the best of my knowledge, there exists no such decomposition. However, the structure of $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Delta}$ is based on the prior knowledge about my Hankel matrix. Is there any possibility, to use this knowledge in the decomposition?

Comment: Are you trying to derive $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ given $Q$ and the fact that $Q=\Gamma\Delta$?

Comment: Yes, The $Q$ matrix is given and the structure of $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are also known. This structural prior will result in unique decomposition of $Q$.

Comment: I cannot see how this is possible. If $RR^T=I$ then $Q=\Gamma\Delta=\Gamma R R^T \Delta = \Gamma ' \Delta '$. I am probably not understanding the problem...

Comment: It is true that is the decomposition is not unique. But I have particular structure as prior for the decomposed matrices $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$. My question is can this be used in the decomposition, such that I get a solution, with the desired structure of the factor matrices?